# Renamed model class still appearing in active admin menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, activeadmin, pg

I had to rename model class in my ruby on rails app due to name clashing with other class sitting in lib directory. Everything is fine when I run app both in production and development env on my local machine, however on old class name is still displayed when running app on heroku. I tried clearing cache (Rails.cache.clear and rake tmp:clear), restarting server, even deleting AA models directly on heroku. Nothing seems to works - old model is still in the menu. The renamed model is also displayed in AA menu. I'm using ActiveAdmin 0.6.0.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename the modelname.rb file in app\admin or delete it if you generated a new resource

Comment: Also did you run migration on heroku?

Comment: I run migration on heroku. I did rename model file in in app/admin. I run project wise search for any references of renamed (old) class. I can not find any references to old class!

Comment: Ok, so you renamed the file in app/admin but in the first line did you change `ActiveAdmin.register Modelname do` to the new modelname